# My Checkboxlist does not show multiple data from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am trying to bind my Checkboxlist programatically based on two input variables ; but i get only one checkbox instead of 3 .

Here are my codes

This is my Business Layer

```
 public class BALDisplayPanel2
{

    private string _mylabel;

    public string MyLabel
    {
        get { return _mylabel;  }
        set { _mylabel = value; }
    }

    private string _conditionlabel;

    public string ConditionLabel
    {
        get { return _conditionlabel; }
        set { _conditionlabel = value; }
    }


    private string _checkboxquestion;

    public string CheckBoxQuestion
    {
        get { return _checkboxquestion; }
        set { _checkboxquestion = value; }
    }
```

This is my Data access Layer

```
 public List<BALDisplayPanel2> DisplaySPanelQ(int tbid, int grdid)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mynewdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("esp_MyCheckboxProc", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        List<BALDisplayPanel2> lst = new List<BALDisplayPanel2>();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", tbid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitNumber", grdid);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            BALDisplayPanel2 unt = new BALDisplayPanel2();
            unt.CheckBoxQuestion = dr["CheckQuest"].ToString();
            unt.MyLabel = dr["MyLabel"].ToString();
            unt.ConditionLabel = dr["ConditionLabel"].ToString();

            //unt.LabelS = dr["LabelQ2"].ToString();
            lst.Add(unt);
        }

        conn.Close();
        return lst;

    }
```

This is my Default.cs file i call my checkbox

```
        BALDisplayPanel2 bl = new BALDisplayPanel2();
        DALDisplayPanel2 dal = new DALDisplayPanel2();
        List<BALDisplayPanel2> lst = new List<BALDisplayPanel2>();
        lst = dal.DisplaySPanelQ(Convert.ToInt32(tbEmpID.Text), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text));

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {

            chbklstpanel3.Items.Clear();
            chbklstpanel3.DataSource = lst;
            chbklstpanel3.DataTextField = item.CheckBoxQuestion;

            lblpanel3.Text = item.MyLabel;
            lblCondition.Text = item.ConditionLabel;


            }
```

any help appriciate

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you doing there is looping the result and binding the checklistbox inside it. So here if you have three records then it will loop three times. You also mentioned that clear() the checkboxlist inside the loop. So when it comes third time it will clear the checkboxlist and bind only the last record. Thats what you are getting only one record on the checkbox list.

so remove the foreach loop,

```
    BALDisplayPanel2 bl = new BALDisplayPanel2();
    DALDisplayPanel2 dal = new DALDisplayPanel2();
    List<BALDisplayPanel2> lst = new List<BALDisplayPanel2>();
    lst = dal.DisplaySPanelQ(Convert.ToInt32(tbEmpID.Text), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text));


        chbklstpanel3.Items.Clear();
        chbklstpanel3.DataSource = lst;
        chbklstpanel3.DataTextField = item.CheckBoxQuestion;
        chbklstpanel3.DataBind();
```